Keycloak executeAction.ftl template: action variable is undefined
I'm customizing the executeAction.ftl template in Keycloak to change the email content based on the action that triggered the email (e.g., UPDATE_PASSWORD, VERIFY_EMAIL). However, I'm facing an issue where the action variable seems to be undefined. Even using a null check or default value doesn't resolve the problem, and it always goes to the else clause.
<#-- Header -->
<#include "header.ftl">

<#-- Email content -->
<div class="content">
    <p>Hello ${user.firstName},</p>

    <#-- Check which action generated the email -->
    <#if (action == "UPDATE_PASSWORD")>
        <p>We have received a request to update your password. Please click the link below to update your password:</p>
    <#elseif (action == "VERIFY_EMAIL")>
        <p>Please verify your email address by clicking the link below:</p>
    <#elseif (action == "UPDATE_PROFILE")>
        <p>Please update your profile by clicking the link below:</p>
    <#else>
        <p>Please click the link below to complete the requested action:</p>
    </#if>

    <p><a href="${link}">${link}</a></p>

    <p>Thank you,<br/>
    The Support Team</p>
</div>

<#-- Footer -->
<#include "footer.ftl">


You don't try to handle the null case in your example.
